# Minimal-effort Multiple Table Inheritance (MTI) support in Laravel 7.x

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance, laravel-7

I have stumbled upon a couple of examples of MTI implementations in Laravel, but they do not satisfy me because it appears that the examples re-model the original abstraction of the problem, to make it work with the framework, I suppose. I am trying to confirm this, or otherwise figure out how--what I want--can be done in Laravel 7.x. The official docs don't seem to include the category of example, for model inheritance, that I require, or I failed to find it within my 3 hour research.

```
# Tables
#

Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();
  $table->string('license_plate_number');
  $table->string('type');
  $table->timestamps();
}

Schema::create('electric_cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->foreignId('car_id')->constrained('cars')->primary();
  $table->integer('battery_capacity');
}

Schema::create('gasoline_cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->foreignId('car_id')->constrained('cars')->primary();
  $table->integer('tank_capacity');
}

# Models
#

class Car extends Model
{
  //
}

class ElectricCar extends Car
{
  //
}

class GasolineCar extends Car
{
  //
}

# Usage
#

@foreach (GasolineCar::all() as $car)
  <td>{{ $car->license_plate_number }}</td>
  <td>{{ $car->tank_capacity }}</td>
@endforeach
```

I have read about $with, the -able pattern, among other things, and they require me to re-model the abstraction of my implementation into one that is less intuitive for me, not reflecting the OOP hierarchy in the same way, at least from my perspective. I am hoping that Laravel is "smart enough" to dynamically add the properties from the superclass/supermodel, in the same way as demonstrated under Usage.

How may I achieve the above example with the least amount of code and modification to my models and tables, by simply following the conventions to eliminate unnecessary property overriding?

Answer (score 0):

This is all I have found about it:

https://github.com/cvsouth/eloquent-inheritance

I think STI and MTI should be a built-in feature in Laravel along with polymorphic relationships.